# how to return CheckBoxTile tital as my code returning only true or false when is select checkbox

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

CheckBoxTile..
CheckboxListTile(
title: Text("Painting"),
value: _checkBox1,
onChanged: (value){
setState(() {
_checkBox1=value!; )

Printing it from List..
return CardItems(

```
                Person.personsList[index].intrest1,
                
          }),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fQ9l.jpg)

Comment: Please provide full code. so, can get idea about it.

Comment: Can you explain more about code-snippet, what are you trying to archive, what gets wrong and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE]".

Answer (score 0):

With an item in the list, you add a boolean variable to check if it is selected or not.

```
class Model {
  String name;
  bool isSelected;
}
```